# Paste data validation only using Google Apps Script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This one should be an easy yes or no. Is it possible to paste data validation *only* with Google Apps Script?

What I want to do is have the code copy the data validation from the row above the active cell, then paste the data validation into the row of the active cell.

I tried copyTo:

```
function updateFormat() {
  var rowNumber = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSelection().getRow();
  var rowAbove = rowNumber -1 ;
  var targetRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, 36);      
  var templateRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(rowAbove, 1, 1, 36);

  templateRange.copyTo(targetRange);
}
```

but--obviously--that copied the data validation *and* the *contents* of the row above, which is not the goal.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the optArgument {formatOnly:true} works ([See Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#copyTo)). So

```
templateRange.copyTo(targetRange);
```

becomes

```
templateRange.copyTo(targetRange, {formatOnly:true});
```

I've refactored your code slightly and tested using:

```
function updateFormat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowNumber = sheet.getActiveSelection().getRow();
  var rowAbove = rowNumber -1 ;
  var maxCols = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(rowAbove, 1, 1, maxCols);
  rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 1, 1, maxCols), {formatOnly:true});
}
```

Comment: mhawksey, you're the MAN! Adding the optArgument did EXACTLY what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, I think that there is a [new validation class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation#copy%28%29) to solve these issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is a variant of copyTo that paste only the data validations:

`copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION)`

On your specific case, instead of

```
templateRange.copyTo(targetRange);
```

use

```
templateRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION);
```

Ref. [range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed)

Answer (score 0):

No.

But as a workaround, you could read all other values, formulas and formatting of your `targetRange` before you copy the template over it, then restore them using their specific formulas, e.g. `setFormula`, `setValue` and so on. Basically leaving only the data validation from the template.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Copia en la fila nueva el formato y validaciones de la fila maestra, es decir, 
 * la cabecera si index = 1 o la que prefiramos, si no expecificamos index, cuando 
 * insertamos al final coge de maestra la anterior y al principo coge la siguiente.
 * @example function onEdit() { updateRules(); }
 **/
function sheetRowRules(index)
{
  var spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row   = sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();
  var cols  = sheet.getMaxColumns();

  if (index)
    var i = index;
  else if (row > 2)
    var i = row-1; // anterior
  else
    var i = row+1; // siguiente a la cabecera
  var rg     = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, cols);
  var rango  = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, cols);

  // Copia el formato del anterior registro al actual y fórmulas de celdas para conservar validaciones de datos
  rg.copyTo(rango, {formatOnly:true});
  var formulas = rg.getFormulasR1C1().toString().split(",");

  //rango.setFormulasR1C1(formulas); // borra los valores, por eso así:
  for (var n = 0; n < formulas.length; i++)
  {
    if (formulas[n].length)
    {
      var col = n+1;
      var rango  = sheet.getRange(row, col, 1, 1);
      rango.setFormulaR1C1(formulas[n]);
    }
  }
  spread.toast("Formatos y fórmulas del replicados de "+i+" al registro "+row);
}
```

Comment: No offense but this site is English speaking, you're not supposed to write in Spanish.. Many people around here are not native English speaking but they make an effort!