# data validation based on adjacent cells in a google spreadsheet

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The sheet I am using is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As4zIxUmN7bjdDlQWjZodWJSaE5kMHFOM0pORzBjUHc).

I want to take the validation in column F, Row 2, and apply it to all rows of column F based on the respective values in columns B and C for each row.

E.g.  A2 = Pittsburgh, B2=Philadelphia, F2 is a dropdown for either "Pittsburgh" or "Philadelphia".   A116=CAROLINA, B116=PHILADELPHIA, then F116 should be a dropdown for either "CAROLINA", or "PHILADELPHIA".

I found [this example script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696499/paste-data-validation-only-using-google-apps-script) that will copy just the validation, however I will need to add a counter to increment each source cell in the validation for each row that it applies to.

Comment: It would be helpful if the spreadsheet example was actually shared, even read-only.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something: isn't this just a matter of writing a script which will create a validation rule referencing the list range consisting of the adjacent cells in column A and B relative to the cell in column F.

If 'cellInF' references the current cell in focus, then

```
   var validList = cellInF.offset(0,-5,1,2);
   var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validList, true).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
   cellInF.setDataValidation(rule);
```